# Dapper QueryMultiple Get the actual values from the DB

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

The dataset return 4 data tables as resultset but all in object{string} type even though in the table it is of different data types like int.

```
var ds = new DataSet();
        return  var ds = WithConnection(c =>
            {
                var multi = c.QueryMultiple(sql: "StoredProcedureName",
                                             param: new { Project = projectID },
                                            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

                while (!multi.IsConsumed)
                {
                    var dt = ChngDataTable(multi.Read());
                    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                }

                return ds;
            });

   protected DataTable ChngDataTable(IEnumerable<dynamic> items)
        {
            var exisData= items.ToArray();
            var dt = new DataTable();
            if (exisData.Count() == 0) return dt;
                
            foreach (var key in ((IDictionary<string, object>)data[0]).Keys)
            {
              if(!dt.Columns.Contains(key))
          dt.Columns.Add(key);
            }
            foreach (var d in exisData)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(((IDictionary<string, object>)d).Values.ToArray());
            }
            return dt;
        }`
```

Is there any easy way to get the values with the actual data type from the DB as I cannot use any properties

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

please, take a look on the https://dapper-tutorial.net/querymultiple example.
You can use parameterised version of the Read method in order to get the type of choice.

If I understand the idea correctly, you would like to get data in the form of DataTables, then change DataTables and then do something with them.
In this case I'd split the work into stages in order to benefit from statically typed C# language.

1) Retrieve a result from database
2) Map to the POCO objects (like it is done in the example above)
3) Change fields according to a business logic
4) Map objects back to DataTables (either custom code with Reflection or any nuget package of choice).

Comment: Actually I am new here. Could you please give an example?

Comment: Actually I cannot use the parameterized Read as I cannot use any properties. I have 5 dataset returning from the stored procedure and it’s a lot of columns. Any other way to get the actual data type instead of string.